# Rails Validator - Only Alphanumeric and not all Numeric

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to get a 'Twitter-like' validation working. That means

```
- Only alphanumeric and not all numeric
```

but I'm stuck at the regexp. Can someone help me out with that specific regular expression?

`validates :user_name, with: 'elmagicoregexp'`

Comment: for number and letters or only numbers /^[0-9a-zA-Z|0-9]+$/. You can try that

Answer (score 10):

You can use

```
validates :user_name, with: /^[A-Za-z0-9]+$/
```

which accepts only number and digits
or you can try
[Rails format validation -- alphanumeric, but not purely numeric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13897431/rails-format-validation-alphanumeric-but-not-purely-numeric)

Comment: will this allow uppercase letters? Or should `A-Za-z0-9` be used?

Comment: if you want to allow upper case then /^[A-Za-z0-9]+$/

Comment: I assume the OP wants to include upper case. So I'd include that. As for now, good answer ;) +1

Comment: Seems nice, i forgot a small thing :P It can't accept only numbers. Can you add that ? THanks